# MsgBox on server side

Tags: ajax, vb.net, postback, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to display a popup message on my web app. When i run my app normally on my local pc, i get the pop up message boxes appear. However when i publish the app they dont.

here's how it will work:
a button is pressed, it will pick up a file from a directory, then it will check another directory to see if the file the exists...if the file exists then a pop up is needed to inform "File already exists. do you want to continue?" if the user clicks yes it carried on with the code, if they click no then the process is ended.

do anyone have any idea how to do this?

my code so far:

```
If System.IO.File.Exists(acceptedExistsuNKNOWN) And System.IO.File.Exists(rejectedExistsUNKNOWN) Then
          'IF BOTH EXIST
            If MsgBox(acceptedExistsuNKNOWN & " & " & rejectedExistsUNKNOWN & "files already exists, do you want to rerun the process?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Files Exists") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
(continur
else
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess.Kill()...
```

many thanks

Comment: You really want the message to appear on the webserver, not to the client?

Comment: sorry i meant i need the message to pop up so the client can see it, but when i publish my web app it does not pop up. ill edit this now

Comment: Right - the MsgBox is a serverside thing - it'll pop out of the server side code and not the website. You need to return to the client to get the confirmation, and then come back to the server again to perform the action. This is more messy. It might be a better plan to give an upfront checkbox saying "Overwrite existing files", rather than asking once you find the problem file.

Comment: this will not be possible because the user might not want to over write the files if they exist so i need to ask them whether they want to overwrite them or not.

Comment: What I'm saying is, ask them before hand in principle rather than explicitly. They can always run once without allowing overwrites, get the fails, then decide its ok to run again with the overwrites.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your idea is that someone would need to sit logged in to the server to interact with the modal popup boxes; that is, if this was even possible, since it would need to be *that* person *on the server* who *does the action on the page* in order to be the recipient of the popup, so it's not like other users can issue a popup to *him*.

What you do on the server side executes on the server side.

I think you really want ti to *show* on the client side, but want the logic to make it happen on the server side. It doesn't work this way. Instead, what you might do is output something n the response that *indicates* a client-side popup should be shown. For instance, you could have a hidden field on the page and set a value, then use JavaScript to show an alert *if* that value meets your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you are asking.  If a dialog pops on the server side, the user will not be able to see it (they are on the client side).  Moreover, the code will be at a standstill until someone dismisses that dialog, which the user cant see.  Only individuals with access to the server will be able to see this.  Do you intend to have someone watching the server 24/7?  Instead, you probably want to alert the user.  This can be done my returning a response from the server code to the client code to display a dialog.  The simplest method would be to throw an error and redirect the user to a new page to display an error.  If you want something more fluid, you can use updated panels and the AjaxControlToolkit's modal pop up extender.  Another way would be to use ClientScript, like this:

```
try
{
    //check for files here
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string script = "<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>";
    if (!Page.IsStartupScriptRegistered("myErrorScript"))
    {
         Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript("myErrorScript", script);
    }
}
```